# jQuery AJAX call (POST to PHP) issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to use the `$.ajax()` call within jQuery to post a little bit of JSON to my PHP script.

I have tried everything but nothing works as I would like it to. I simply try to echo a var_dump of the $_POST/$_GET arrays but it comes back empty.

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [{"conversation": _conid} ]};
var obj = $.toJSON(myJSONObject);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./code/ajax/fetch_messages.php",
    data: obj,
    async:true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
    },
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) 
    {

    },
    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) 
    {
  }});
```

I can see that the post is made by looking in the headers:

{"bindings":[{"conversation":"38x001c61450ad4d5abd47c37408e8236eb5427f54e2930000306882646e4016c5f8ecf8e00a18a26ab3b6d07f6727bd187625daaedf951f93072d54d59e300e100"}]}

PHP:

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

Everything works great when using the `$.post()` call but I always run in to problems when I try to switch to `$.ajax`. I need to use it to be able to retreive the response UTF-8 encoded.

The code pasted in this post is just one of many snippets I've tried, even examples from tutorials on the web does not work.

Could someone please give me a snippet that you know do work so I can try that? Sending JSON through POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must give your json string a key, so you can get it on the other side (PHP):

```
data: {"myjson": obj},
```

Then on PHP it will be in `$_POST['myjson']`

Comment: No, that did not work. It changed the format of the sent header from json to
myjson=%7B%22bindings%22%3A%5B%7B%22conversation%22%3A%2238x001c61450ad4d5abd47c37408e8236eb5427f54e2930000306882646e4016c5f8ecf8e00a18a26ab3b6d07f6727bd187625daaedf951f93072d54d59e300e100%22%7D%5D%7D

Comment: Try removing the 'contentType' line from `$.ajax` options, or set it to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: Yeey! that was the issue! Thanks. Strange that the tutorials did not see it as a problem.

Answer (score 1):

below is a slice of my routine and it works fine :

```
var data = 'post_type=' + post_type.val() + '&page_id=' + 
 page_id.val() + '&home_page='
 + home_page.attr('checked') + '&archive_page='  + 
 archive_page.attr('checked') + '&search_page=' + 
  search_page.attr('checked');


    //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "?service=set_data",

            //GET method is used
            type: "GET",

            //pass the data        
            data: data,    

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: true,

            //success
            success: function (html) {                          
                    $(".no-items").hide("slow");
                    $("#list_table").append(html).hide().slideDown('slow');              
            }      
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have any issues with when using "get" not sending json.